How to make first word first character capital of each sentence in HTML (Is it possible?)
I don't have a complete code for this just planning for something,
assume that we have a simple HTML Text Box like this:


 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sentence Case Validation</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Text Validation: Sentence Case</h2>
    <form>
        <label for="textBox">Enter your text:</label><br>
       <textarea id="textBox" 
          pattern="^([A-Z][a-z]*[.!?]\s?)*$" 
          title="Each sentence must start with an uppercase letter, followed by lowercase text, and end with . ? or !."></textarea>

        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>



In this Text Box, I want each sentence's first word first character to be capitalised (Uppercase).
I know maybe it's not logical in HTML, and I know it can be handled in JS easily, which is mentioned here How to make first word first character capital of each sentence but in this question, I am just asking for the possibility of having it in HTML
I tried different Regex, like this one :
^([A-Z][^.!?]*[.!?]\s*)+$

but in the end, ChatGPT says it's impossible, because of Regex limitations, and responds this:

The limitation lies in the HTML pattern attribute's capabilities.
While regular expressions (Regex) can handle sophisticated patterns to
some extent, the pattern attribute in HTML is not equipped to enforce
or verify a complex rule. because:Regex for pattern in HTML is
limited: It does not allow for advanced regex features like
lookaheads, lookbehinds, or multiline matching. Complex sentence
logic: Writing a regex to handle sentence capitalization properly,
considering edge cases, spaces, and punctuations, is a non-trivial
task that usually involves scripting (e.g., JavaScript).

So what do you think? is it impossible to use HTML Regex Pattern for this purpose? if no can you help me to write the correct Regex for it?
Thanks

Well, you certainly can't change text with HTML. The only thing you can do with regex is match patterns for validation. But even then, regex validating if all sentences start with a capital is not possible in any sort of general case. Regardless of HTML or not. Because regex cannot delimit sentenes just symbol groups. You could try and make sure that if you have a word character after a . or ! or ?, then it should be capital. But that doesn't map 1:1 to sentences. E.g., this sentence right here contains two . but doesn't stop at them.

Well, if you want to edit the text input into the text field, then pattern attribute is just not the right tool as it only validates. You need to write a JavaScript function to actually modify the input text.

Dear @VLAZ
I don't want to enforce them using HTML, i just want to validate the text if it's following the requirements or not.
So you think HTML is not functional for this and can't achieve these just by using HTML, am i right?

Dear @WiktorStribiżew i couldn't add two mention in one comment, so my previous comment is for you too

The biggest problem is that detecting sentence endings is more complex than regular expressions can handle. You have to distinguish . used for abbreviations, sentences can be inside quotes, etc. Doing it well requires NLP.

@Cham I clearly said, and explained with an example, that REGEX ITSELF cannot do it. HTML is not involved in detecting sentences and regex works on different patterns than what natural language provides you with. You can sort of work around it by throwing a lot more regex but you'd end up making an unmaintainable mess of a pattern. That still likely wouldn't accurately detect what is or isn't a sentence or a capital letter.

@VLAZ Thanks, i understand it, but i have a client who doesn't understand! and says i WANT HTML PATTERN for this!

¯\(ツ)/¯ they can provide one, if they so desire.

Tell the client to pay us, not you. We seem to do the work here, not you.

Can JavaScript/HTML detect sentenses? Kind of. Is it foolproof? Absolutely not.

OK, but it is really a very hard thing to make work for any arbitrary text. There are abbreviations to consider. If you say you do not care, then all you need is something like pattern="\p{Lu}[^?!.]*[?!.](?:\s*\p{Lu}[^?!.]*[?!.])*".

Have a go with WinkNLP, a JS Natural Language Processing library that you can also run in the browser. See how to build it for the browser and play with this live example extracting sentences from a text. If you also split the user's input text into sentences, you can then check or uppercase each first letter from them.

I think, this might help you @Cham https://jsfiddle.net/2hv7fky1/1/

I don't need it anymore and seems its impossible, so we just used js

The pattern attribute for the textarea element is not currently supported.https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-textarea-element
When using the input element, the HTML only validation as outlined works as expected. The provided regex pattern was very close to what ended up working for me (added some punctuation, space, and the letter I characters to match the most common use cases):
^(?:[A-Z][a-zI',;\s]+[\.!\?]\s?)+$



#textBox {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 300px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  outline: none;
}

#textBox:valid {
  border: 2px solid #00ff00;
}

#textBox:invalid {
  border: 2px solid #ff0000;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Sentence Case Validation</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>Text Validation: Sentence Case</h2>
  <form onsubmit="return false;">
    <label for="textBox">Enter your text:</label>
    <br />
    <input pattern="^(?:[A-Z][Ia-z',;\s]+[\.!\?]\s?)+$" type="text" id="textBox" name="textBox" title="Each sentence must start with an uppercase letter, followed by lowercase text, and end with . ? or !." required />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
</body>

</html>

<!--
excluded punctuation
" # $ % & ( ) * + - / : < = > @ [ \ ] ^ _ ` { | } ~
-->



Though it satisfies the required format as outlined in the title attribute, this solution only works for basic sentence structures (not for all punctuation, proper nouns, etc.).
